# Should I install ia32-libs or lib32stdc++ or can I just use --force-all for 32-bit printer driver

Tags: printing

I got a Brother printer MFC class. The brother website only provides 32-bit drivers but I installed 64-bit Ubuntu. It says I need to install "ia32-libs" or "lib32stdc++" to install the 32-bit drivers onto 64-bit Ubuntu. Elsewhere I've read that I don't need to install these packages, I can just use --force-all when installing, but I don't know of the accuracy of this information. My questions:

1) do I HAVE to install "ia32-libs" or "lib32stdc++" or can I use --force-all to make 32-bit drivers install on 64-bit ubuntu?

2) if I do have to install "ia32-libs" or "lib32stdc++", which should I install? Which is better, which is recommended by ubuntu experts?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed ia32-libs on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and it took long time to install.
I am happy to say that now my brother MFC J280W started working!

[This Brother web page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html) helped me.